# Facebook API (Javascript): Posting to a friendlist

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, friend

Can someone point me in the right direction for publishing a post to a friendlist using the Facebook JS API? I have so far been using this code:

```
    FB.api('me/feed', 'post', { message: msg,privacy: {value: "CUSTOM", friends: "SOME_FRIENDS", allow:selected_list}}, function(response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            console.log(response);
            console.log('ERROR ERROR ERROR');
        }
        else {
            console.log(response);
            console.log('successfully sent, now reload data');
            refreshData();
        }
    })
```

In this case, *selected_list* is the id for the friend list. I have also tried passing in a list of ids to post to my friends walls using a string like this: "aID,bID,c_ID,d_ID"

It seems to be posting to my own wall but not to my friends walls and more important does not show up in the friendlist feed. I can post comments on a feed easily but can't create new posts and have them shared among my friends within that list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The code you wrote posts to your own wall.. The API is posting to `me/feed` which is nothing but your own wall.. It should be `FRIEND_ID/feed`

```
FB.api('/FRIEND_ID/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
```

The above code posts the message to the friend's wall with the FRIEND_ID. Hope this helps.

Comment: With a friendlist is it not possible to simply post to the entire group using a single unified call? Perhaps replacing the friend_id with the id of the friendlist?

Comment: Haven't tried posting to the friendslist, I was getting the selected friends ids and posting individually. Will try and will let u know.

Comment: I don't think posting to the friendlist_id instead of the friend_id will be feasible because `post` method deals with creating a post on the users wall and a friendlist_id is not a `USER` it is just a list of friends like a contact list.

Answer (score 1):

Your using the deprecated format for the privacy object.  I suspect that is your issue.

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { 'message': msg, 'privacy' : {'value': 'CUSTOM',
      'allow':'uid1,uid2,flid1,flid2'}}, function(response) {

    }
});
```

And don't try to use spaces in your comma separated list.  I spent 3 hours before figuring out that you can't do that.